Possible solution to the 3x3 magic square of squares problem
I think I might have a solution to the problem of the existence of 3x3 magic square of squares problem and have written a ten page paper detailing most of the stuff, but I fear no-one is going to open a link to a shared PDF on the internet, so here's the quick and dirty version that maybe sparks interest.
(Please know I am very much aware of the fact that amateur mathematicians rarely get such big scores, so I doubt very much all of this is correct. But consider my side - if I think I may have succeeded, what am I to do but to post it and have others tell me what I did wrong? This being said, I'm sorry to have taken your time to read what will probably boil down to a bunch of nonsense and I thank you for it.)
A 3 x 3 magic square is a set of square integers
\begin{bmatrix}
A^2 & B^2 & C^2 \\
D^2 & E^2 & F^2 \\
G^2 & H^2 & I^2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
such that the sum of elements in each row, column and diagonal is the same. This can be parameterized as follows:
\begin{bmatrix}
t^2 + (t^2- \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2}) & t^2 - (t^2 - x^2) & t^2 - \frac{x^2 - y^2}{2} \\
t^2 - (t^2 - y^2) & t^2 & t^2 + (t^2 - y^2) \\
t^2 + \frac{x^2 - y^2}{2} & t^2 + (t^2 - x^2) & t^2 - (t^2- \frac{x^2 + y^2}{2}) \\
\end{bmatrix}
This means the middle row, middle column and the diagonals form an arithmetic progression of squares with the congrua $K_1 = t^2-x^2$, $K_2=t^2-y^2$, $K_3=t^2-\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}$ and $K_4=\frac{x^2-y^2}{2}$. We know that for an arithmetic progression of squares, the middle element is of the form $m^2+n^2$, and the congruum is of the form $4 m n (m^2-n^2)$. This would imply that the middle element $t$ must have four unique representations as a sum of two squares, which implies it must be of the form $t=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)(e^2+f^2)$ and the exact formulas for those four unique representations in terms of these six variables are given by the Brahmagupta–Fibonacci identity:
\begin{equation}
v_1 = a c e - b d e + b c f + a d f
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_2 = a c f - a d e - b c e - b d f
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_3 = a c e - b d e - b c f - a d f
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_4 = a d e + a c f + b c e - b d f
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_5 = a c e + a d f + b d e - b c f
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_6 = a c f + b c e + b d f - a d e
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_7 = a c e + b c f + b d e - a d f
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
v_8 = a c f + a d e + b d f - b c e
\end{equation}
So we have this:
\begin{equation}
t=v_1^2+v_2^2=v_3^2+v_4^2=v_5^2+v_6^2=v_7^2+v_8^2
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
K_1 = 4 v_1 v_2 (v_1^2-v_2^2)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
K_2 = 4 v_3 v_4 (v_3^2-v_4^2)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
K_3 = 4 v_5 v_6 (v_5^2-v_6^2)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
K_4 = 4 v_7 v_8 (v_7^2-v_8^2)
\end{equation}
Now, we can set up four equations:
\begin{equation}
E_1=K_1+K_2-2K_3=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
E_2=K_1-K_2-2K_4=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
E_3=K_3+K_4-K_2=0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
E_4=K_3-K_4-K_1=0
\end{equation}
By introducing two polynomials in terms of which we can rewrite them (details in the PDF)
\begin{equation}
P(x, y) = x y (x^2-y^2)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
Q(x, y) = x^4-6x^2y^2+y^4
\end{equation}
like so
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    E_1 & = \left(8 \, P(c, d) \, Q(e, f)\right) \, Q(a, b) \\ 
    & - \left(256 \, P(c, d) \, P(e, f) + 8 \, Q(c, d) \, Q(e, f)\right) \, P(a, b)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    E_2 & = \left(-16 \, P(c, d) \, Q(e, f) - 8 \, P(e, f) \, Q(c, d)\right) \, Q(a, b) \\
    & - \left(128 \, P(c, d) \, P(e, f)\right) \, P(a, b)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    E_3 & = \left(-4 \, P(c, d) \, Q(e, f) + 4 \, P(e, f) \, Q(c, d)\right) \, Q(a, b) \\
    & - \left(- 192 \, P(c, d) \, P(e, f) + 4 \, Q(c, d) \, Q(e, f)\right) \, P(a, b)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    E_4 & = \left(-4 \, P(c, d)  \, Q(e, f)- 4 \, P(e, f) \, Q(c, d)\right) \, Q(a, b) \\
    & - \left(- 64 \, P(c, d) \, P(e, f) - 12 \, Q(c, d) \, Q(e, f)\right) \, P(a, b)
\end{split}
\end{equation}
We can use these equations to create two homogeneous linear systems of $Q(a, b)$ and $P(a, b)$, which only have non trivial solutions where the associated matrix has determinant equal to zero. In other words, we have:
\begin{equation}
\begin{vmatrix}
8 \, P(c, d) \, Q(e, f) & 256 \, P(c, d) \, P(e, f) + 8 \, Q(c, d) \, Q(e, f) \\
-16 \, P(c, d) \, Q(e, f) - 8 \, P(e, f) \, Q(c, d) & 128 \, P(c, d) \, P(e, f)
\end{vmatrix}
 = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{vmatrix}
-4 \, P(c, d) \, Q(e, f) + 4 \, P(e, f) \, Q(c, d) & - 192 \, P(c, d) \, P(e, f) + 4 \, Q(c, d) \, Q(e, f) \\
-4 \, P(c, d) \, Q(e, f) - 4 \, P(e, f) \, Q(c, d) &  - 64 \, P(c, d) \, P(e, f) - 12 \, Q(c, d) \, Q(e, f)
\end{vmatrix}
 = 0
\end{equation}
Evaluating these determinants we get these two equations:
\begin{equation}
P(c, d) \, Q(c, d) \, \left(32 \, P(e, f)^2 + 2 Q(e, f)^2\right) + P(e, f) \, Q(e, f) \, \left(80 \, P(c, d)^2 + Q(c, d)^2\right) = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P(c, d) \, Q(c, d) \, \left(32 \, P(e, f)^2 - 2 \, Q(e, f)^2 \right) + P(e, f) \, Q(e, f) \, \left(16 \, P(c, d)^2 + Q(c, d)^2\right) = 0
\end{equation}
Switching to a polar parametrization of the six variables
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    a=r_{ab} \cos\left(\theta_{ab}\right) \\
    b=r_{ab} \sin\left(\theta_{ab}\right) \\
    c=r_{cd} \cos\left(\theta_{cd}\right) \\
    d=r_{cd} \sin\left(\theta_{cd}\right) \\
    e=r_{ef} \cos\left(\theta_{ef}\right) \\
    f=r_{ef} \sin\left(\theta_{ef}\right) \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
we get the following a lot of simplification, because:
\begin{equation}
P(c, d) \, Q(c, d) = \frac{1}{8} \sin(8 \, \theta_{cd}) \, r_{cd}^8
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
32 \, P(e, f)^2 + 2 \, Q(e, f)^2 = 2 \, r_{ef}^8
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
P(e, f) \, Q(e, f) = \frac{1}{8} \sin(8 \, \theta_{ef}) \, r_{ef}^8
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
80 \, P(c, d)^2 + Q(c, d)^2 = \left(3 - 2 \, \cos(8 \, \theta_{cd})\right) \, r_{cd}^8
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
32 \, P(e, f)^2 - 2 \, Q(e, f)^2 = -2 \, \cos(8 \, \theta_{ef}) \, r_{ef}^8
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
16 \, P(c, d)^2 + Q(c, d)^2 = r_{cd}^8
\end{equation}
This simplifies the two equations we got from evaluating the determinants to:
\begin{equation}
2 \sin(8 \theta_{cd}) + \left( 3 - 2 \cos(8 \theta_{cd}) \right) \sin(8 \theta_{ef}) = 0
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
2 \cos(8 \theta_{ef}) \sin(8 \theta_{cd}) - \sin(8 \theta_{ef}) = 0
\end{equation}
Merging these two equations we get the following equation:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
(\cos(8 \theta_{cd}) - 1)^2 \left(\cos(8 \theta_{cd}) + 1 \right) \left(2 \cos(8 \theta_{cd}) - 1 \right) = 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Solving it gives us the following solutions:

Case when $\cos(8 \, \theta_{cd}) = 1$

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\theta_{cd} = \frac{\pi \, i}{4}, i \in \mathbb{Z}
& \implies \begin{cases}
    \tan(\theta_{cd}) = 0 & i \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \implies d = 0 \\
    \tan(\theta_{cd}) = 1 & i \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \implies d = c \\
    \cot(\theta_{cd}) = 0 & i \equiv 3 \pmod 4 \implies c = 0 \\
    \cot(\theta_{cd}) = -1 & i \equiv 4 \pmod 4 \implies c = -d
\end{cases} \\
& \implies \textbf{trivial solutions}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Case when $\cos(8 \, \theta_{cd}) = -1$

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\theta_{cd} = \frac{1}{8} (\pi + 2 \, \pi \, i), i \in \mathbb{Z}
& \implies \begin{cases}
    \tan(\theta_{cd}) = \sqrt{2} - 1 & i \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \\
    \tan(\theta_{cd}) = \sqrt{2} + 1 & i \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
    \tan(\theta_{cd}) = -\sqrt{2} - 1 & i \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \\
    \tan(\theta_{cd}) = -\sqrt{2} + 1 & i \equiv 3 \pmod 4
\end{cases} \\
& \implies \tan(\theta_{cd}) \not\in \mathbb{Q} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Case when $\cos(8 \, \theta_{cd}) = \frac{1}{2}$

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\theta_{cd} = \frac{1}{8} \, \left(-\frac{\pi}{3} + 2 \, \pi \, i \right), i \in \mathbb{Z} 
& \implies \begin{cases}
    \tan(\theta_{cd}) = 2 - \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{6} & i \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \\
    \tan(\theta_{cd}) = - 2 - \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6} & i \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
    \tan(\theta_{cd}) = 2 + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6} & i \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \\
    \tan(\theta_{cd}) = -2 + \sqrt{2} + \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{6} & i \equiv 3 \pmod 4
\end{cases} \\
& \implies \tan(\theta_{cd}) \not\in \mathbb{Q}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\theta_{cd} = \frac{1}{8} \, \left(\frac{\pi}{3} + 2 \, \pi \, i \right), i \in \mathbb{Z}
& \implies \begin{cases}
    \tan(\theta_{cd}) = - 2 + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6} & i \equiv 0 \pmod 4 \\
    \tan(\theta_{cd}) = 2 - \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3} + \sqrt{6} & i \equiv 1 \pmod 4 \\
    \tan(\theta_{cd}) = - 2 - \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{6} & i \equiv 2 \pmod 4 \\
    \tan(\theta_{cd}) = 2 + \sqrt{2} - \sqrt{3} - \sqrt{6} & i \equiv 3 \pmod 4
\end{cases} \\
& \implies \tan(\theta_{cd}) \not\in \mathbb{Q} 
\end{split}
\end{equation}
However, note that due to our setup, all the solutions given in (70), (71) and (72) are invalid, because the following must hold:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
d \neq 0 \implies \frac{c}{d} = \cot(\theta_{cd}) = \cot\left(\frac{\pi \, i}{4}\right) \in \mathbb{Q} \\
c \neq 0 \implies \frac{d}{c} = \tan(\theta_{cd}) = \tan\left(\frac{\pi \, i}{4}\right) \in \mathbb{Q} \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Thus, the only possible solutions lead to either a trivial solution (considered in the PDF) or to a contradiction, proving there are no magic squares of squares.
The PDF detailing all of this (for example, discussing why trivial solutions do not yield a valid magic square) is available for download here.
Full disclosure: I've posted this PDF in a response to my own question I posed on Math StackExchange that I asked a year ago when I though I had found a solution, but was shown otherwise. Math StackExchange post

It would be useful if this question defined what a "magic square of squares" is. In any case this appears to address only the 3x3 version.

@DanielAsimov, you are correct, I added the information to both the title and the introduction. Thank you for your comment...

Welcome to MathOverflow! I suspect that this question (a question of the form "here is some work I did, can you check it?") is one of the disallowed types of questions for this site. See the page in the help center for on-topic questions, under the heading "MathOverflow is not for asking people to check your (or other people's) work".

Sadly, asking for correctness of proofs to open conjectures is off-topic by long-standing convention. I hope your proof stands up! It might be worth trying to contact mathematicians who are interested in such a thing, for instance those who are mentioned/interviewed in Numberphile videos on the topic. One way for a brutally honest assessment is to post a link to this in r/math in Reddit. People there will definitely let you know if you made a mistake. Best of luck!

@Daniel, the $3\times3$ case is the one that has been discussed in the literature.

I agree with @David and will be voting to close. An additional place to post your work is arXiv or, if you can't do that, then viXra.

One of the things that (often, but not always) distinguishes good mathematical work from "a bunch of nonsense" is the good mathematical work builds on the previous good mathematical work of other investigators, and cites it. Much work has already been done on the $3\times3$ magic square, yet you don't cite any of it – you don't even have a references section at the end of your pdf. If you have built on the work of others, you must cite them, and if you haven't bothered to see what your predecessors have done, why not?

I should add that mathematicians that work on or adjacent to famous open problems (for instance one popularised on a big YT channel) almost surely have to deal with many, many people contacting them and saying they have a solution, and it is almost surely never a solution, for a number of reasons. The tips here are always good when thinking about contacting people about proposed solutions to problems: https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/18570/8881

There is something suspicious about the system of equations $E_1=E_2=E_3=E_4=0$, it seems to me that it already implies that $K_4=0$ and $K_1=K_2=K_3$, which would be a contradiction already. I think the issue is that $E_2 = K_1-K_2-2K_4 = 0$ is not true as written, and it should read $K_1-K_2+2K_4 = 0$ instead. Once this fix is made the conditions $E_3 = 0$ and $E_4 = 0$ are redundant, as they are consequences of $E_1 = 0$ and $E_2 = 0$. This likely spells trouble for the approach, as now you only get that one determinant is vanishing instead of both.

Aha. So the integers that are squared to get the magic square of squares are required to be neither consecutive nor distinct.
